# Github: is it possible to download master archive via ssh (without the git client)

Tags: git, github, ssh

I am trying to connect to a git repository hosted on github from a router.

The router has wget but it does not support ssl connections; github only allows http downloads via ssl. It is not an option to update the firmware of the router to enable wget to support ssl connections; or to update the router with a git client.

The router can however access github via ssh.

For example,

```
ssh git@github.com -i git.key git-receive-pack username/repo.git
```

Is it possible to download either the individual files in the repository or the master archive using a similar ssh command?

The only other alternative I can think of is to setup a web proxy on my remote server so I can use wget to access the repository, but this is adding a dependency to the process.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

if you create a clone using

`git clone --bare ssh://URL/repo.git` you get master archive.

Theoretically if `scp` command in open (it is usually not) you can copy using `scp`

Comment: but that is using the git client, which is not on the router

Comment: you use an intermediate machine to create clone (not bare clone in this case) And then copy stuff over

Answer (score 0):

The Git protocol does not work on files, but history and references. You can pass options to `git-clone`/`git-fetch` such as `--depth 1` and `--single-branch` to produce a similar effect, but if you want to use the `ssh` directly, you'll have to implement the git protocol yourself, which is going to be more trouble than anything else you try to do.

If ssh's SOCKS proxy doesn't help, then you'll have to use that HTTP proxy. With no explanation of why such a system would need to grab arbitrary data from a repository that's not quite a repo, this sounds a lot like an X-Y problem, with this being some corner of a subset of the issue and it would help to evaluate why this is something that would help to solve the problem.

Comment: my thinking was that on a "normal" machine, when git is configured to use ssh and you clone a remote repository, the files from that repository are transferred via ssh...so yes was hoping that there was en easy way to implement the git protocol.


Will probably have to use a http proxy as an ssh SOCKS proxy won't 'translate' https sites to http

Comment: You're describing FTP, or a similar protocol made for file transfer, which is not what version control systems are made for.

Comment: not describing FTP at all...say you run for example `git clone git@github.com:username/repo.git`, you are using an SSH connection to github to retrieve not only the information, but the data from all the files in the repository as well

Comment: so git, in whatever language it is written/compiled in, is acting as a client using the SSH protocol to retrieve the files. I basically wanted to know if it was feasable for something written in shell could do the same...in theory it is...but it would appear to be too much hard work given the (slightly sloppy) alternative of using a middle marchine (in my case running a http proxy)

Comment: You keep talking about a protocol to transfer files. This is not what version control systems are about. The Git protocol is about doing Git stuff; if you want to download a bunch of files, you need something different.

Comment: so when you type git clone blah blah at a command prompt and the files appear from the remote repository onto the local machine, how does that happen if git isn't responsible? git DOES use SSH as a transfer protocol. (or https if you specifiy a https URL)